# In SSRS Report Builder, how to only show something when it's the last row of a group?

Tags: sql, reporting-services

I am trying to build a report to only show specific notes below the LAST line in a grouping, but that grouping may only be part of a data set.

Quick example:
I have two orders with three rows of information each.  After each row, I have a row that is hidden, but when visible displays NOTES.  These two orders are separated by a "line number".  So the data set has 6 rows, but I need to distinguish if a row is the last row of a certain line number, so that the row can then be shown.

Comment: You can add a row inside the group. NOTES is a field in your dataset?

Comment: @alejandrozuleta yes notes is a field, some rows have it, some don't.

Comment: Do you want to show the note below the line only if it is present?

Comment: i can do that, i only want the note to show if it is the last row in a subset of the dataset

Answer (score 2):

I know this is years ago but maybe someone else needs to do this.
Add the row below footer and for its visibility use this Expression:

pretty simple really:  =countrows("DataSet1")<>rownumber("DataSet1")